# Nginx Reverse Proxy Times Out when accessing via mobile data

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, timeout

I have a web server running behind an Nginx reverse proxy setup.
The web app is accessible just fine from Wi-Fi (internet fibre) connections
but times out if it's being accessed via mobile data.

The error page on Chrome reports, among other things:
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The config looks something like this:

```
server {

    server_name         domain-name;

    location /app-path/ {
        proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.14:5000/;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    # more SSL stuff

}
```

The Nginx error log does not seem to report anything related to the problem.

I have tried setting timeout values and replacing `keep-alive` with `""` to no avail.

The proxy server with Nginx can still be pinged successfully on a mobile data connection though.

Any help would be appreciated as I find it quite puzzling how being on mobile data would cause the site to timeout.

Comment: Where is nginx hosted? What mobile provider? Did you try another one?

Comment: The nginx installation is on a box collocated at a data centre. The mobile users are Kenyan and I've been unable to find one on a data plan with a different mobile provider.

Comment: Not in Kenya? Have you done a traceroute?